# Process Cannot be displayed. Failed to process configuration file. Try to restart the application. If failures continue, tryn to repaire your install

Tags: asp.net, .net, nuget, arch

I have tried to run my .net project from different machine. I have installed visual studio 2013 ultimate blend. When i opened and tried to run the project, "Process cannot be displayed. Failed to process the configuration file.Try to restart the application. If failures continue, try to repair your installation"

i have tried to run my project from different machine.